# Limit point of real numbers

Tags: analysis

How to find limit points of the following set of real numbers?(with neighbour)

$A=\{ \left( 1/2^n + 1/3^m\right) : n,m \in \mathbb{N} \}$

I show that if $x=0$ , $x=1/2^n$ or $x=1/3^m$ then $x$ is limit point, but i cannot show these are the only limit points.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Suppose $(x_k)$ is a convergent sequence of distinct points in $A$, with $x_k=1/2^{n_k}+1/3^{m_k}$.  Then either $n_k\to \infty$ or there is some value of $n$ such that $n_k=n$ for infinitely many values of $k$ (why?).  Similarly, either $m_k\to\infty$ or there is some value of $m$ such that $m_k=m$ for infinitely many values of $k$.  In the cases where such an $m$ or $n$ exists, you can pass to a subsequence to assume that $n_k=n$ (or $m_k=m$) for all $k$.

Comment: it is correct, but i cannot used sequences.

Comment: Hmmm...honestly, I think the easiest way to do this "without sequences" is just to prove that every limit point is the limit of a sequence, and then use sequences.  That is, even if you aren't allowed to assume the theory of sequences, you can prove the facts you need about them from scratch.